# Show that if $g(x) = f(Ax + b)$, then $\delta g(x) = A^T \delta f(Ax + b)$

Tags: convex-analysis, subgradient, matrix-analysis

Looking for a simplier expaination for the following:

> Show the following for sub-gradients:
>
> (a) If $g(x) = f(Ax + b)$, then $\delta g(x) = A^T \delta f(Ax + b)$.

I've found the trivial direction using the definition of a subgradient, but I don't really know where to begin finding the other direction.

I know I need to prove that $\delta g(x) \in A^T \delta f(Ax + b)$, thereby showing equality since they are both part of each other. I've read several breakdowns of how to do this and the special cases, but I don't fully understand them. Thanks!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2656013/how-to-prove-the-affine-composition-of-the-subdifferential/2656562#2656562

Comment: Will do, thank you!